# git fetch does not working but pull is working

Tags: git

I was trying to fetch command but it does not doing anything.
and then trying to pull command.
it works.

Why fetch is not working. but pull is working?

sometimes
fetch command is working well..

what's difference?

1/ case one fetch not working

```
**$ git fetch origin privacy_log_project**

From financeSVN/scampus
 * branch            privacy_log_project -> FETCH_HEAD

**$ git pull origin privacy_log_project**

From financeSVN/scampus
 * branch            privacy_log_project -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 1462574..77eec67

Fast-forward
 .../com/test/snu/common/RequestWrapper.java    | 42 ++++++----------------
 .../com/test/snu/config/ApiInterceptor.java    |  2 +-
 2 files changed, 12 insertions(+), 32 deletions(-)
```

2/ case two fetch is working

```
**$ git fetch origin privacy_log_project**

remote: Counting objects: 14, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
remote: Total 14 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (14/14), done.

From financeSVNscampus
 * branch            privacy_log_project -> FETCH_HEAD
   77eec67..2b503cf  privacy_log_project -> origin/privacy_log_project
```

Comment: It looks to be working just fine. `git fetch` won't print extra useless fluff when there is nothing to be fetched; you'll just ge the output you saw.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) will only update the remote tracking branches, in `.git/refs/origin`

If said tracking branches are *already* up to date, nothing happen.

[`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) will fetch (which might do nothing) *and* merge the current branch with its matching remote tracking one (master with origin/master for instance): that second step can produce an additional output and make those `origin/master` files visible in your current `master` branch.

Answer (score 0):

`Git Fetch`

- git fetch command download the changes to your local branch of origin
  by fetch. git fetch commands the remote repository for all commits
  that others have executed but you don't have on your local
  repository. git fetch downloads certain commits and appends them to
  the local repository.

`Git Pull`

- git pull command combines a couple of pull, was created. git pull
  does a fetch and then a merge to append the downloaded commits into
  your local branch.